# F-1 rocket engine - gas generator data

Tags: aerospace-engineering, data, rocketry

I’m doing some research on Rocketdyne F-1 engine of Saturn V. In particular I am searching geometric data of the gas generator that feeds the turbo pump. Has someone found this kind of data? It seems impossible to find online, even on the engine official manual.

Comment: First question : who made the pump?

Comment: @SolarMike i think rocketdyne (?)

Comment: As in Rockwell International? And then you might try contacting Pratt & Whitney...

Comment: @SolarMike yep that could be a option

Comment: @SolarMike To my knowledge, Rocketdyne is part of Aerojet Rocketdyne, Inc. which has nothing to do with Rockwell International.

Comment: Nasa has refurbished one and hot fired it in 2013 in Huntsville. They should have the info. youtube.com/watch?t=7&v=1AD-DbC3e68&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @EricS this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocketdyne

Comment: @PhilSweet i know, saw the video but Nasa doesnt seem to publish data. Instead, i tried to connect on LinkedIn with the chief engineer of that fire test. Lets see if that works

Comment: @SolarMike Evidently it was associated with Rockwell at one time, but not when it developed the F-1 and not currently. Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding. From what I've read, surprising little of the original documentation of the Saturn V still exists and most of the engineers who designed it are no longer alive.